# how to use relative address to read a file in C# winform

Tags: c#, winforms, relative-path, spire

I am using spire library to read a word file in winform in c#.

here is my code:

```cs
Document mydoc = new Document();
mydoc.LoadFromFile(@"C:\Users\user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\FormsPrint\FormsPrint\word\1.docx");
```

but this address is not relative. the problem is I can't move this app to other computers because of its absolute address.

I changed my code to:

```cs
Document mydoc = new Document();
mydoc.LoadFromFile(@"\word\1.docx");
```

but it didn't work again. I used ~/ at first of address but didn't work too. note that the function `"loadfromfile"` is one of spire library functions that gets a string path for input. how can I use relative path? I read other questions and answers like this but didn't work for me. how can I change this address to the relative address?

Comment: `\`` is weird. Some things interpret it as the root of the current partition (e.g `C:\\\``), but some say it's not a valid character to start a path with. And some have weird behaviour. `Directory.Exists("\\")` returns true, but doing `Path.GetDirectoryName` returns null. Instead try using `.\`` or just starting without a `\``. **Edit** backslashes and comments are weird, expect wonky formatting

Comment: Also, what does this question have to do with `spire` (the numeric library for Scala)?

Comment: Are you running in Debug?  If so remember that your executable is in bin\Debug and runs in that folder, so all paths have to be relative to this..

Comment: Make sure you include your `word\1.docx` in your VS solution and then click on it and change `Copy to output directory` to `Copy always`. This way the file will be copied to wherever your executable is build and then run from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to have the `word` folder same location where your `.exe` is:

[image]

then, call it as

```
mydoc.LoadFromFile(@"word\1.docx");
```